# how can I check System Dark mode is enable or not

Tags: java, android, xml

```
binding.switchh.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean check) {
                if(check){
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                }else{
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                }
            }
        });
```

Help me to check switch while system dark mode is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Found this code in the google Android documentation:

Java:

```
int currentNightMode = configuration.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
switch (currentNightMode) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
        // Night mode is not active, we're using the light theme
        break;
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
        // Night mode is active, we're using dark theme
        break;
}
```

Kotlin:

```
val currentNightMode = configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
when (currentNightMode) {
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {} // Night mode is not active, we're using the light theme.
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {} // Night mode is active, we're using dark theme.
}
```

source: [Android docs.](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/darktheme)